# How to exit from php include function?

Tags: php

In php, if file A.php `include` file B.php, how can I (from B.php) stop importing and exit the include. For example consider this pseudocode:

A.php

```
print(0);
include "B.php";
print(1);
```

B.php

```
print(2);
exit();   // <--- this is to show I want to quit the import...
print(3);
```

I expect the output to be: `021`.

Does anyone know how to do this with some sort of function call like `exit` or something?

I don't want to use code blocks such as if statements.

Thanks

Comment: Currently what it printed as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`return;`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) instead of exit().